# How to make shoulder bend properly?

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting, inverse-kinematics

I'm trying to make my shoulder bend properly
and so far it looks like this:
[image]
[image]

but when I try to move my hand it looks like this:
[image]

I was wondering if there was a way I could limit the rotation around the shoulder part (especially around collar.2) so that it doesn't look way out of place

I tired to limit rotation in IK but it doesn't seem to work the way it should:
[image]

so how do I make my shoulder more natural? and how do I control how much each bone rotates in IK?
( also on a side note are there any tutorials on detailed shoulder rigging? )

here's my blend file:
[image]

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to shorten the IK chain (like 4 rather than 5) and move the shoulder bone manually? maybe try a copy rotation constraint for the 5th bone (with a low Influence)?

Comment: @moonboots I've been trying for the last **3 days** could you modify the provided blender file so I can understand what you mean?

Comment: I mean in the IK constraint, choose a shorter chain length? And if you want the shoulder to move, move it manually now that it is not part of the chain?

Comment: @moonboots actually I could solve the entire problem but for some reason this isn't working in my blender: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JuBIiFfrXBY

Comment: what do you mean? what did you solve and what isn't working?

Comment: @moonboots i said i **could** solve my own question but can't because I can't reproduce the same results as given in the video link

Comment: It looks like the IK limit is on the wrong bone.